# How to show angular-bootstrap tooltip dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, angular-bootstrap

I'm trying to show/hide the tooltip dynamically. 
In order to do that I set up custom trigger

```
$tooltipProvider.setTriggers({
    'show':'hide'
});
```

And created a custom directive which triggers 'show' event.

```
app.directive('dynamicTooltip', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
     link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $timeout(function() {
       $element.trigger('show');
      },1000);
     }
  };
}]);
```

However, nothing happens. No errors or something.

Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/zmza9NeqHcE9apsPxSGi?p=preview)

I read the documentation for angular-bootstrap tooltip and lots of SO posts thoroughly, but cannot figure it out.
Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Comment: from docs ...`tooltip-is-open` .... use scope variable to toggle it

Comment: @charlietfl, please show the example. I have already tried that but it did not work for me.

Comment: had to change to version `0.13.4` to make it work. Must be a bug in version you are using  http://plnkr.co/edit/bXiyGYXHub7lN4uzY0Gn?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl maybe related to this? https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/81a38d72613d82bb4d8b5ab44e3bde704a59b056

Comment: Yeah! That seems to be a bug. On my local project I have `0.13.4` installed but still had this issue. I manually applied the mentioned patch and it solved the issue. Please post a reply so I can accept it. It will probably help the others, who had the same problem.